# Prove that for any positive integer n there is a sequence of n consecutive composite numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

for n = 4, the consecutive numbers 24,25,26,27 are all composite

For the example above, I see that they are all modulo 22, such as 23=1(mod 22) and 24=2(mod 23)

How do I go about proving it? Should i use the idea above?

Please help!

Comment: 23 is not composite.

Comment: Start with $(n+1)!+2$.

Answer (score 2):

The number $(n+1)!+k$ is clearly greater than $k$, and is divisible by $k$ if $k\le n+1$, so the following sequence contains certainly composites:
$$(n+1)!+2,\quad (n+1)!+3,\dots,\quad (n+1)!+n,\quad (n+1)!+(n+1)\,.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let us try the given hint in comment, as well as the answer.

Let $n=5, n+1=6, (n+1)!= 720$

$k=0$ is obvious.

$k=1$  is also obvious .

$k=2: 2 | 722$

$k=3: 3 | 723$

$k=4: 4 | 724$

$k=5: 5 | 725$

$k=6: 6 | 726$

So, get instead of $n+1$, get $n+2$ consecutive values.

So, need prove that the number $(n+1)!+k$ is divisible by $k$ if $k<= n+1$.

Say, $k = n+1$, then $(n+1)(n)! + (n+1) = 
(n+1)((n)! +1)$.

$k = n$, then $(n+1)(n)(n-1)! + n = 
n((n+1)(n-1)! +1)$.

$k = 2$, then $(n+1)(n)(n-1)...(2) + 2 = 
2((n+1)! +1)$.

$k=1$, then $(n+1)(n)(n-1)...(2) + 1 = 
((n+1)! +1)$
is confusing, as

$(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)..(2)(1) +1
= 1((n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)..(2)+1)$

cannot be proved formally to be a composite.

A case where $k=1$ fails is $n=2$, leading to $(n+1)! = 6$, leading to $(n+1)!+1=7$, a prime.

$k=0$, then $(n+1)!$ is composite.

But, only can take from $k=2$ onwards.
So, hint is correct.